# Simple Google App Script returning "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following Google App Script. Can set breakpoints but they are  never hit.  I am running in Script editor with Calendar API enabled.  It is deployed as an API executable.  I have other following but it was removed to make it as simple as possible.

```
function listCalendars() {  
    calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the line, where it is pointing out and check if the error is really with this function or not. You can also use debugger and [execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) to figure out the issue. Also try to search it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). I saw many ticket issue about your problem.